# Method to understand existing perl code?

Tags: perl, documentation, reverse-engineering

I've got some perl code (about 300-500 lines) that I've got to get working again. I've got limited experience programming, and normally if I'm coding I just find the best solution that make sense to me as is. In this case, I've got to use this code because it's built for an existing legacy system, for which the code is the documentation for the wiring, logic and rendering of the system. It's not a lot of code, but I also can't post even chunks of code or data to get help. What's the best method of understanding the syntax, what it's doing, how the code is wired, how the logic is model, etc.

Questions, feedback, comments -- just comment, thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the book
[Perl Medic, Transforming Legacy Code](http://isbn.nu/9780201795264), by Peter Scott, from 2004.

A few review notes, including a table of contents, are listed at [this perlmonks node](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=347552).

A brief review is [here](http://dave.org.uk/reviews/medic.html).

The book covers many techniques in enough depth to learn & apply them to your problem.  If you only have a little time, scan the whole book, then I recommend Chapter 3 on testing, Chapter 4 on rewriting, and Chapter 11, A Case Study (30+ pages).

If you don't use this book, at least use perldoc to learn Test::More and related modules.  Having useful tests that exercise the original and modified code will build your confidence in making changes, because you can see when a specific change causes a test to fail.

Update.

See this book for more detailed data on Perl's test tools than given in Perl Medic:
[Perl Testing: A Developer's Notebook](http://isbn.nu/9780596100926), by Ian Langworth & chromatic, 2006.

Comment: +1 for the appropriate literature

Comment: +1 Wow, that's a pretty cool book... :-) ...thanks for sharing the reference to the book, and all the additional info on it! Have you used the system presented in the book before? If so, what's your opinion of the hidden gems within it, and/or weakness to any aspects of the approach rendered by the author? Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders: Some highlights of Perl Medic.  **Chap.1**: Reasons for Inheritance, might guide you in deciding level of effort to apply, and some questions to have answered.  **Chap.2**: Finding dependencies.  **Chap.3**: Testing Legacy Code is only 1.5 pages.  **Chap.4**: Why Are You Doing This; and The Ten Levels of Perl (maintenance) Programmers.  Rewriting may be the best choice if you have good requirements docs.  **Chap.6**: Keep It Brief.  Divide code into subs w/ good names.  **Chap.8**: Maybe CPAN has code to replace some or all of your project.  **Chap.9**: Step thru w/ debugger.$

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago I read nice text about understanding large project quickly on perlmonks - [Swallowing an elephant in 10 easy steps](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=788328). There are many useful suggestions that can pay off.

Comment: +1 Pretty amazing process for self-orietation to an existing code base -- thanks for sharing the link! Have you used the system before? If so, what's your opinion of the hidden gems within it, and/or weakness to any aspects of the approach rendered by the author? Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders I used hints from the text many times, it gives good suggestions where to look. It is very useful to gather any available documents or user-level doc to get idea what program does. From that I explore inputs/outputs and its formats, storage (database schema) and points where they are processed. Then I usually dig into the code, find entry points and overall layout. At that point I am usually familiar enough to make some changes and test results. Functional test-suite would be also great resource to understand parts of code, although I never took over program with it available.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look for tools like [perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) which will regularize the formatting.

Also consider running the code in the debugger, and stepping through line by line. See [`perldoc perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to start with the functions... go through the code, find everywhere a function is used and determine if it is a regular perl function that is universal, or if it is a custom function.  Then search the code and find where all of the custom functions are created and determine what each individual function does.

Add comments to the code as you go, once you figure out what a function is doing, add a comment.

That alone should give you a good head start.

In more nitty gritty, you may want to go through after that and label/comment/make note of what each perl variable is used for/what it is the first time it is used.

That should get you well on your way to figuring the code out... and if there is a function or something else you can't figure out, search the web using the wonderful Google... or post here not necessarily with the exact code, as you said you can't, but with a general idea of what it is doing.

Also, one thing I forgot to mention, is to find any loops, whether `while`, `for`, etc and determine what is running inside of them and what they are being looped through.

Comment: +1 Sounds like a plan, thanks. Guessing there's no way to trace if a function is internal (aka custom) to the script, or if it's using Perl's library or CPAN, right?

Comment: Easiest way I know is to simply search through the code and every time you come to a function being used, say like **`validate_perl()`**, copy just the name of the function "validate_perl" and then do a find and search through the code for any other references.  If it is a custom function, obviously one of the times **find** detects it is where it will be getting defined.  There may be a easy way, but I can't think of one right now...  Good luck, you have quite a project ahead of you by the sounds of it.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the extra info, makes sense -- unless some post an super, super answer I expect to pick you as the answer in the next day. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

There have been some good suggestions already, another one is the [`B::Deparse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B%3a%3aDeparse) module, which attempts to rewrite your code (often) in a longer clearer way.

For example when you run `perl -MO=Deparse ob.pl` on the file `ob.pl` containing this [obfuscated code](http://perl.plover.com/obfuscated/):

```
@P=split//,".URRUU\c8R";@d=split//,"\nrekcah xinU / lreP rehtona tsuJ";sub p{
@p{"r$p","u$p"}=(P,P);pipe"r$p","u$p";++$p;($q*=2)+=$f=!fork;map{$P=$P[$f^ord
($p{$_})&6];$p{$_}=/ ^$P/ix?$P:close$_}keys%p}p;p;p;p;p;map{$p{$_}=~/^[P.]/&&
close$_}%p;wait until$?;map{/^r/&&<$_>}%p;$_=$d[$q];sleep rand(2)if/\S/;print
```

You get:

```
@P = split(??, '.URRUUxR', 0);
@d = split(??, "\nrekcah xinU / lreP rehtona tsuJ", 0);
sub p {
    @p{"r$p", "u$p"} = ('P', 'P');
    pipe "r$p", "u$p";
    ++$p;
    ($q *= 2) += $f = !fork;
    map {$P = $P[$f ^ ord $p{$_} & 6];
    $p{$_} = / ^$P/xi ? $P : close $_;} keys %p;
}
p ;
p ;
p ;
p ;
p ;
map {close $_ if $p{$_} =~ /^[P.]/;} %p;
wait until $?;
map {<$_> if /^r/;} %p;
$_ = $d[$q];
sleep rand 2 if /\S/;
print $_;
ob.pl syntax OK
```

Which is (possibly) better; I don't know, maybe not. Worth a try anyway.

Edit: you can get even a little more info by changing the command to `perl -MO=Deparse,-p ob.pl` which puts in explicit parentheses which can help understand operator precedence.

Comment: +1 If I use regex to take out all all the newline, tabs, spaces, etc. -- from both the source-version and the B-Deparse verse would they match? It want to make sure there's a control in insure the code is not being changed; clearly this doesn't apply to the "insert explicit parentheses" argument version. If you know the perl regex to do the check between the before and after, even better. Thanks!

Comment: @blunders, no the versions are slightly different, split's delimiters are changed (not sure why thats a good thing here actually) and it is made explicitly into its 3 argument version also the second `map` command is reordered from two commands joined with an &&, to the second command with a posfix condtional on the first.

Comment: cont) I would hope this doesn't change the the codes operation, but certainly it is not just a whitespace issue. I refer you to the module's documentation "Description" section for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't there any comments in the program that can let you know what each line or each function is doing?

I would go through the code from start to finish. Using a pen and lots of paper. This were the author of the program should have written test cases, so that new programmers, like yourself, can understand how the code works. Not many programmers write test cases.

Comment: It's not proper, confusing legacy code if it has comments!

Comment: @Ben: +1 Too true, funny thing is there is a comment in the header, and it has nothing to do with how the code works... :-)

Comment: Correction: It's not proper, confusing legacy code if it has relevant, useful comments :)